# Passport can not generate refresh token

Tags: laravel

Can you please help me ?

I want to generate refresh token in passport.

I can generate a refresh token only if I use default hash password from Laravel. What I mean is this situation: I create a new registration (from registration form)  and try to call the api in Postman with both email and password.

```
   $http = new Client();
        $response = $http->post('http://localhost/passport/public/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => '2',
                'client_secret' => '**************',
                'username' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'scope' => ''
            ],


        ]);
```

> But the problem is that I don't use hash password which laravel has by
>   default. I am using another hash password and when I call the API
>   http://localhost/passport/public/oauth/token in postman it shows this
>   error :

```
Client error: `POST http://localhost/passport/public/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_credentials","error_description":"The user credentials were incorrect.","message":"The user credential
```

Comment: try adding this in request  'refresh_token' => 'the-refresh-token'

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new hashing driver as a standalone class by extending the `Illuminate\Hashing\AbstractHasher` class and implementing `Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher` interface.

After that you have to register your custom driver in the HashManager class. To do so, in the **register** method of a service provider put:

```php
// Include the class at the top of your service provider
use Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager;

// Then in the register method
HashManager::extend('driverName', function ($app) {
    // Replace the namespace and class with the one you have created in the first step
    // Or resolve it from the app container
    return new \App\Your\Custom\Hash\Driver();
});
```

Once you have done that you can set the same **driverName** you have chosen when you extended the HashManager in the `config/hashing.php` file, by setting the `driver` attribute.

In this way you replaced the default bcrypt hashing systemwide and the credential matching should work without any further modification.